# Where went the Rancher 2.3.1 menu to create a registry?

Tags: docker, dockerhub, rancher

I am following some documentation to deploy a rancher service using a private project on docker hub but I fail to find the place to add a registry. Older version displayed it in the menu :

[image: before]

On my version, impossible to find it
[image: now]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually just randomly stumbled over it:

go to your project -> Ressources -> secrets : there you'll find a tab "registry credentials" where you can add you private registry

I really don't know why you would hide it there, but happy they didn't remove it for good :)